# Python Regex to replace whole word including some special characters

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and was wondering how the following could be implemented. For example,
I have a css file with `url('Inter.ttf')` and my python program would convert this url to `url('user/Inter.ttf')`.

However, I run into a problem when I try to avoid double replacement. So how can I use regex to tell python the difference between `url('Inter.ttf')` and `url('/hello/Inter.ttf')` when using re.sub to replace them.

I have tried `re.sub(r"\boriginalurl.ttf\b", "/user/" + originalurl.ttf, file)`. But this seems to not work.

So how would I tell python to replace the whole word
`'Inter.ttf'` with `'/user/Inter.ttf'` and `'/hello/Inter.ttf'` with `'/user/hello/Inter.ttf'`.

Comment: try `re.sub('^/?','/user/',file)` would result in `Inter.ttf` -> `/user/Inter.ttf`; `/hello/Inter.ttf`->`/user/hello/Inter.ttf`. https://regex101.com/r/ntKFKy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `look-around` method to insert the `/user/` dynamically:

```
(?<=url\(')/*(?=(?:.*?Inter\.ttf)'\))
```

And then use `re.sub` to replace with `/user/`:

```
strings = ["url('Inter.ttf')", "url('/hello/Inter.ttf')"]

p = re.compile(r"(?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?Inter\.ttf)'\))")

for s in strings:
    s = re.sub(p, "/user/", s)
    print(s)
```

```
url('user/Inter.ttf')
url('user/hello/Inter.ttf')
```

### Pattern Explanation

`(?<=url\(')`: Positive lookbehind; matches strings that come after a string like `url('`.

`/?`: Matches **zero** or **one** forward slashes `/`. This is important for matching paths like `/hello/Inter.ttf` because it starts with the `/`. This is going to be selected and replaced with the ending forward slash in the replacement string, `/user/`.

`(?=(?:.*?Inter.ttf)'\)`: Positive lookahead; matches strings that come **before** a string that ends with `Inter.ttf')`.

I suggest playing around with it on https://regex101.com, selecting the `Substitution` method on the left-hand-side.

### Edit

If you want to match multiple fonts, you can just remove the `Inter.ttf` part of the regex:

```
(?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?)'\))
```

Alternatively, if you wanted it to append `/user/` to paths that had a file extension, you can replace `Inter\.ttf` with `\.\w{3}`, which effectively matches 3 of any character in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

```
(?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?\.\w{3})'\))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But how would I do append `'/user/'` to all elements of the list,  if the list is `strings = ['Inter.ttf', '/hello/Inter.ttf', 'hello/Gothic.ttf', 'hello/GG.png', 'GG.png' ]` etc.

Comment: Thank for the edit. So to clarify, if I wanted to use it with re.sub in order to replace all instances in a file would I put `file = re.sub((?<=url\(')/?(?=(?:.*?\.\w{3})'\)), '/user/', file)` ?

Comment: @JongbinWon yes, that's the idea. Make sure you have a backup of the file before you overwrite it just in case something goes wrong!

Comment: Thank you this seems to work. However I run into a small problem. How do I ensure the regex does not catch urls such as https://www.google.com?  In addition, how would I ensure that both `url(Inter.ttf)` and  `url('Inter.ttf')` are caught by the regex. Thank You @gmdev

Comment: @JongbinWon replace `\w{3}` with `(ttf|png)`. Using the `|` is like saying *this **or** that*. Now it's only going to match URLs that have `ttf` or `png`. Keep in mind that there is not limit to the amount of `|` in this expression, so you could do something like this: `(ttf|png|jpg|csv|txt)`

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to do that is like this without regex:

```
fin = open("input.css", "rt")
fout = open("out.css", "wt")
for line in fin:
    if "'Inter.ttf'" in line:
        fout.write(line.replace("'Inter.ttf'", "'/user/Inter.ttf'"))
    elif "'/hello/Inter.ttf'" in line:
        fout.write(line.replace("'/hello/Inter.ttf'", "'/user/hello/Inter.ttf'"))
    else:
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: I don't think it's a single string but rather the whole css file as a string no?

Comment: we can do it for a file simple wait i update it

Comment: He wants to use sub to replace all instances I believe. That's harder and slower to do with .replace

Comment: already i done it with replace , u can give it a try i update the code